# Android radio button custom attributes

Tags: java, android

I have a 4 static radio buttons.
I want to add custom attributes to radio buttons.

```
RadioButton btn_radio1= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_radio1);

//I just can change id of element,than get it.
btn_radio1.setId(44);
```

Thanks.

---UPDATED
XML

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/btn_radio1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="TEST" />
```

Comment: you have missed the closing bracket

Comment: Do you initially create your rButtons in a XML layout or programmatically?

Comment: I use it static from xml. Pro grammatically I used for check boxes ,it was easy for me to put a data(cursor) from the database

Comment: than post also your xml radio buttons and group definitions.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use Id to store data on Android components/views as this id is set by the system and is not supposed to be changed. If you want to store your own id, you could use the tag property of the component with setTag(...), or extends the `RadioButton` class from the framework to add your own properties.

Comment: Yes i know that I should'n store data in id.Now I'm trying to use "setTag" Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I get your question, you don't have access to other setter, except setId() ?
If that's the case, you're probably doing something wrong. It should be possible to get the radio button (like in your code) and have access to other set methods, not only setId();
This link could be helpful : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons

If you want to add custom attributes (e.g. make a custom component, that behaves like RadioButton), look the two links below:

1) http://hugman.posterous.com/parameterizing-a-custom-components-to-promote

2) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: I need to put some information to radio buttons.(custom attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the links!Its what I need to know.